# Polynomials generating primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Does there exist a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients with $f(0)=1 or -1$ such that $f(x)$ is a prime for all $x$ in $N$?

If $x$ can be $0$ ,then, it is easy.
But I cannot get it if $x$ cannot be $0.$

Comment: The condition $f(0)=\pm 1$ is unnecessary. A non-constant polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients cannot be prime for all natural numbers $x$.

Comment: But I do not know how to prove it if $f(0)$ is $1$ or $-1$

Comment: No. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions).

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(1)=p$. Then, $p | P(kp+1)$ for all natural numbers $k$. As $P(kp+1)$ is prime, $P(kp+1)=p$ for all $k$, meaning $P(x)-p$ has infinitely many roots. Contradiction, as $P$ is non-constant.

Answer (score 0):

No. The only polynomials which are prime at all positive integers are the constant polynomials $P(x) = p$ for $p$ prime, but none of these have $P(x) = \pm1.$